How to exit from Paint Text regime and preserve the letter? Letter disappears upon exiting if I wrote the letter starting from the left of the bmp
I have 16*16 pixel BMP, and I am trying to add big capital letter A over this picture. I am trying to do this in Microsoft Paint program.
The usual and expected scenario is:

I am selecting Text regime;
I am clicking with the left eye of the mouse in the pic, the text editing box appears;
I am writing a letter, I can select the letter and format it. I can also pull the borders of the letter to place in the expected position;
[now comes the most confusing part] I want to exit from the text regime, preserve the letter and expect it that Paint converts it in the pixel content (doing the necessary fuzzification, blurring). I am clicking with the left eye of the mouse outside the text box but still inside the picture. And now the scenarios diverge.

Sometimes the letter is preserved and pixelization is done. And sometimes the letter just disappears. I can not catch the exact cases when and what happens, but I have observed, if the letter is placed in the right half-plane of the picture and if I am click in the right half-plane, then the letter is preserved and pixelized. But if the letter is big, and I need to work and click with mouse in the left half-plane as well, then the text is lost, and the picture stays as nothing has been done on it.
I have searched Web and there are suggestions that selecting Select tools closes the text regime and preserve the picture, but it is not so for me.
I am using Windows 10 and 'About Paint' reports 'Version 22H2'. But I am not sure whether such basic feature can work differently across versions. It is a bit strange to lose control over such a small issue.
